# sed using regex example

Tags: regex, sed

I'm going over some legacy code and found this code:

```
cat some_file | \
sed "/^\/${CATEGORY}\/latest\//s: /.*$: ${DATA_PATH}:"
```

The format of the original file looks like:

```
/car/latest/    /US/car/2017/04/02
/bike/latest/   /US/bike/2017/03/31
/boat/latest/   /US/boat/2017/04/03
```

Assume the CATEGORY above is bike, and the DATA_PATH is /US/bike/2017/04/02, I guess the output will be like this, otherwise it does not make any sense.

```
/car/latest/    /US/car/2017/04/02
/bike/latest/   /US/bike/2017/04/02
/boat/latest/   /US/boat/2017/04/03
```

If so, what does the `"s: /.*$:"` do here? Why doesn't "/boat/latest/   /US/boat/2017/04/03" get substituted since we are replacing to the end (using the dollar sign).

If not, then what will be the output?

Thanks!

Comment: What are CATEGORY and DATA_PATH?

Comment: It seems like the regex is trying to match `latest/` (followed by a slash) but the file does not have slashes after `latest` so there will not be a match. Maybe try `/^\/${CATEGORY}\/latest/s:...`

Comment: Hi Explosion Pills, yes you're right I missed the slash after latest. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the sed part is the issue, let us break it down:

/^/${CATEGORY}/latest// -- So this first part says to find all lines that follow this pattern, assuming CATEGORY = bike --- ^/bike/latest/. Note that ^ means the line must start with this

s: /.*$: ${DATA_PATH}: -- Once we have found lines matching the above this replacement is performed.  first note is that the "normal" / delimiter has been replaced by :.  Now if you look closely, it reads like this -- match a space followed by / and then all characters until the end of the line.  the 'space' is the key as the only place on each line where you find a space followed by / is at the start of the second column, namely :- /US/bike/2017/03/31, using our bike example.  The replacement portion also uses "space" + DATA_PATH

if we take a single line of our data (where we have bike), the matching portion is:

```
/bike/latest/   /US/bike/2017/03/31
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Note how the first ^ is prior to the / in front of US

Answer (score 0):

The expression will match `/bike/latest/` in your example. The `/.*$` substitution replaces space followed by slash followed by any characters up to the end of the line. If `DATA_PATH` is the same as what is being replaced then this actually does nothing. Try replacing `DATA_PATH` with something else and you can see the substitution.

Just to clarify, the substitution replaces everything after a slash that is preceded by a space. There are no spaces before any of the category paths, e.g. `/bike/latest/`